# SQL Query - extracting data between html tags in a text column into new table

Tags: html, sql

A web form was developed and instead of saving individual fields the whole form was saved in a text column as html.  I need to extract data between various html tags so want to create a query that writes each set of tags to a table for me to then use - if this is possible please can someone advise how this can be achieved.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've noticed you weren't happy with my last answer, however i am still certain you need server side code to handle SQL queries. Basically without having any sort of server side code you wanna do something like "here's a TV i bought, and here's the DVD release of the "John Wick" movie, i wanna watch it on this TV. Without a DVD player you can't really do it tho', that is the role of the PHP or ASP.NET in this case. Since I am not familiar with PHP, I am only able to show a solution in ASP.NET C# which i put together some time ago.

Here's how I solved this in a site i've built some time ago. It is not the cleanest, but it most certainly worked.

In ASP.NET you have the page file, which is similar to a HTML or an XML file, using a lot of pointy brakcets. Create one like this:

**page file, body:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="HiddenTextBox" style="display: none;" runat="server"
onclick="OnStuff" OnTextChanged="TheUserChangedMe"
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

scroll up a bit, and in the  section add some javascript, where you can handle on text change instantly. So as soon as something happens, like the user clicks on an image, or... well does anything you want him to do (and respond to that) you need the ID of that element he clicked on.

**page file, head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MarkItems_onclick() {
var Sender = window.event.srcElement;
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenTextBox.ClientID%>').value = Sender.id;
__doPostBack('<%= HiddenTextBox.ClientID%>', 'TextChanged');
}
</script>
```

**page's .cs file, the C# code behind**

```
//
//add these on top:
//

using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

//
// later somewhere write this:
//

protected void TheUserChangeMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserRegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
//
```

**Note:** the connection string has to be set up earlier. make sure you make one, visual studio will let you do that in no time. Do not forget, that this connection string defines where your DB is located, and grants the required information for the site how to even reach it at the first place.

```
// 
// somewhere you need to read out what you have in your HiddenTextbox:
//

String stringToProcess = HiddenTextBox.Text;
```

process your stuff, here i assume you cut it up accordingly and you will have an insertQ variable with a proper syntax. in order to add these values it should look something like this:

```
String insertQ = "insert into OrdersTable(OrderId, Type, Quantity) " + 
                                  "values (@OrderId, @StuffType, @StuffQuantity)";
```

How to access the database in asp.net C#:

```
conn1.Open();

SqlCommand insertComm = new SqlCommand(insertQ, conn1);

insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", nonStringVariable.ToString());
insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StuffType", aStringVariable); 
insertComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StuffQuantity", "some random text");             
insertComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn1.Close();
```

that's pretty much it. Your SQL database will have 3 fields filled up every time this function runs. It's a bit messy, but for my site it was crucial to  handle any onclick event, and with this you can flush out 23 checkboxes, 10 pictures and whatnot as page elements, yet you'll know what happened every time the user clicked something.

Answer (score -2):

i'm not a professional either, however i think you're gonna need something on the server side to process this query, like asp.net or php. Basically the server side code would have no problem generating your page's content according to what comes back from the DB.